# Apache Spark multiple job to access single method

Tags: scala, asynchronous, apache-spark, rdd

Say I have 5 jobs that wants to access single method that will read this big file and put it to RDD. Instead of reading this file multiple times (because there will be 5 jobs that will do the same method), there's this "mother" class that will check if there already exist a job that already called the method.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that these 5 jobs are executed in a sequence, then you can read the file and cache it `<RDD>.cache(...)` in the first job itself and rest all job can check if the file already exists in cache then just use it, else read it again.

for more info, Refer to [RDD API](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD).